# video inside hidden-xs hidden-sm is downloaded?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm creating a website, and inside a div I have a video, but I don't want to show this video on mobile devices, so I use hidden-xs and hidden-sm, so far so good.

but, my question is, when I use these classes the video is not downloaded or just is not shown? because, there is a huge difference between them, thinking on data consumption on mobile data plan.

Using Dev Tools on Chrome, on network tab using 3g, does not show if its downloaded or not.

So, how to be 100% sure what to use? hidden-xs and sm or CSS media queries?

And, I'm completely aware of useragent, but, there is a thousand of them. So I will need to specify each one of them. I have a snippet for that, but I don't think is a good idea at all... unfortunately...

cheers =D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a browser dependent situation. In general the browser won't show hidden things, even in media queries.

And to prevent the video download **you won't need JavaScript**, simple add `preload: none` or `preload: metadata` (if you want to retrieve basic informations about the file) as a `video` attribute.

Quote from [the `<video>` specification](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/video#HTML_Attributes)

> `preload` = "**none**" or "**metadata**" or "**auto**" or "" (*empty
>   string*) or empty   Represents a hint to the UA about whether
>   optimistic downloading of the video itself or its metadata is
>   considered worthwhile.
>
> - *"**none**": Hints to the UA that the user is not expected to need the video, or that minimizing unnecessary traffic is desirable.*
> - *"**metadata**": Hints to the UA that the user is not expected to need the video, but that fetching its metadata (dimensions, first
>     frame, track list, duration, and so on) is desirable.*
> - *"**auto**": Hints to the UA that optimistically downloading the entire video is considered desirable.**
> - *Specifying the empty string is equivalent to specifying the value "auto".*

Comment: Swell.... its seems more rational than using any other ways.... thanks very much!

Comment: I just did a test on Chrome using "preload=none" but is still being loaded on Network and Sources as well.... this is getting weird....

Answer (score 3):

It's downloading, it's verified by using Chrome debug tool connected to phone, that the file is still being downloaded. So solution is to add video with js.

Use this html for adding video:

```
<video preload="none" class="hidden-xs" autoplay="autoplay" poster="fallback-image.jpg" loop="loop" id="myVideo">
</video>
```

but first detect mobile devices with javascript and add video when it is not mobile browser:

```
function detect() { 
    if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)
       || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)
       || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)
       || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)
       || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)
       || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)
       || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)){

        // If mobile browser

    } else {
        // If not mobile
       document.getElementById("myVideo").innerHTML = '<source src="video.webm" type="video/webm"><source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">';
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's downloading because you ask for metadata information.

Comment: @kakajan..... do you mind to redo this same test but using "preload=none" to be sure please? I broke my mobile yesterday and i can't make this test at this time... cheers

Comment: opps, sorry, do it with preload=none, don't use metadata

Comment: swell then!! Thanks very much! =D